# Google Cloud SDK - gcloud alpha datastore indexes create

Tags: indexing, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud

Initially we had 2 projects , one for firestore and other for datastore
Trying to use Multiple database feature of Google Cloud. When I try to create indexes using the command :
gcloud alpha datastore indexes create "filename" --database=mydatastore1

I get the error : (gcloud.alpha.datastore.indexes.create) ALREADY_EXISTS: index already exists

The same command works perfectly well if i work in previous configuration

Comment: Have you tried `gcloud datastore indexes list` if `INDEX_FILE` already exists. Check this reference on [`gcloud datastore indexes`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/datastore/indexes) for additional information.

Comment: Looks like this may be a bug in gcloud.  We've added a fix that will be in the next gcloud release.

Answer (score 1):

Posting as a community wiki based on @JimMorrison which is a Googler based on his profile:

> Looks like this may be a bug in gcloud. We've added a fix that will be in the next gcloud release.